# SqlAlchemy Flask - association table with more than two columns

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a shopping cart, for this I am using the following models in Flask:

```
line_item = db.Table('line_item',
                     db.Column('cart_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cart.id')),
                     db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id')),
                     db.Column('price', db.Float)
                     )


class Cart(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Unicode(64), index=True, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Unicode(500), index=True, unique=True)
    image_url = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    line_item = db.relationship('Cart', secondary=line_item, backref=db.backref('products', lazy='dynamic'))
```

I want to use an extra column in the association table "line_item" to include price in order to save the price of a product at the moment the user adds it to the cart.

I know that without the `price` column I would do the following to add this data.

```
p = Product()
c = Cart()
p.line_item.append(c)
db.session.add(p)
db.session.commit()
```

How am I supposed to insert the `price` in the association table?

Comment: Why would the price change between the user adding to the cart and checkout? Additionally if the price does change wouldn't you want to charge the proper price and display the correct price when they go to checkout?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `db.Model` for your `LineItem` - untested code as follows:

```
class LineItem(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'line_items'        
    cart_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('carts.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id'), primary_key=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Float)    
    cart = db.relationship("Cart", back_populates="line_items")
    product = db.relationship("Product", back_populates="carts")


class Cart(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'carts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    line_items = db.relationship(LineItem, back_populates="cart")    


class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'  
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Unicode(64), index=True, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Unicode(500), index=True, unique=True)
    image_url = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    carts = db.relationship(LineItem, back_populates="product")    


p = Product()
c = Cart()

line_item = LineItem()
line_item.price = p.price
line_item.product = p

c.line_items.append(line_item)
```